# Spring - can't load bean information in service

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

I'd like to ask how should I load bean (defined in application xml) in my service class in Spring application. I've tried to load it using (and simillar solutions):

```
public class MyService {
   public void myMethod() {
      ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("security-config.xml");
      LdapPersonDAO ldapPersonDAO = (LdapPersonDAO) context.getBean("ldapPersonDAO");
   }
}
```

security-config.xml

```
<bean id="ldapPersonDAO" class="shdb.ldap_sync.dao.LdapPersonDAO">
 <property name="ldapTemplate" ref="ldapTemplate" />
</bean>
```

but no solution works for me. Is there any standard solution?

Thanks for any help,

Mateo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/security-config.xml"), though it would help if you provided more details on the errors you are getting.

Also, you should avoid lookups and MyService class should be also declared in app context and have ldapPersonDAO injected declarative. Then users of MyService would also have it injected, and so on up to the very main class of your application which you get from the app context as well.

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't provided the error message I thought that I'm wrong so the error message wouldn't be needed. Anyway, the problem still persists. I have my security-config.xml in WEB-INF/spring folder so I've tried every possible combination of path and the error is still same

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [security-config.xml];
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [security-config.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist

Is there any solution?

Comment: I've solve it following your advice. I've loaded the bean right in the place where I need it (controller) and it works. I've used following code:
WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(request.getSession().getServletContext());
LdapPersonDAO ldapPersonDAO = (LdapPersonDAO) webApplicationContext.getBean("ldapPersonDAO");